# Django: didn't return a HttpResponse object error

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am trying to make a Post form, but HttPResponse occurs.In my code, there is a redirect method, and I think it is considered as a httpresponse, isn't it?

I am just a begineer, so if someone could find an easy mistake, I would appreciate

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from .forms import DayCreateForm


def index(request):
    return render(request,'diary/day_list.html')


def add(request):

    form = DayCreateForm(request.POST or None)


    if request.method == 'POST'and form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('diary:index')

        context ={
         'form':form
        }
        return render(request,'diary/day_form.html',context)
```

Comment: There are some formatting issues with your code in this question. Without knowing if this is just a copy-paste issue or not, it looks like your `return render` line needs to be un-indented

Comment: Can you try cleaning up the code and then it will be easier to help

Comment: hi, thanks for your help. I edited and it is now as the code in my editor.

Comment: as you said, apparently it was related to an indent related issue!! thanks, I really appreciate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code there is no `HttpResponse` returned if `request.method` is not `POST`,  so try to add a return of HttpResponse in the case of 'not Post'.

Comment: ah, ok like the comment of JPG above?? sorry, I am just a begineer. so I don't quiet understand terms!

Comment: It's okay. In `view.py`, always return an HttpResponse in functions no matter what case.

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning any HTTP response if the requested method other than *`HTTP POST`*. So, try the below snippet

```
from django.http.response import HttpResponse


def add(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DayCreateForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('diary:index')
        else:
            return HttpResponse("form is not valid")
    else:
        form = DayCreateForm()
        context = {
            'form': form
        }
        return render(request, 'diary/day_form.html', context)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for you help. I tried it, but it couldn't connect to a server. I will try something else!! Thank, you though

Comment: Ehhh...What you mean by *"couldn't connect to a server"*? I don't get that